# Google Chrome stays in leftmost space in Gnome Application-Switcher

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, google-chrome, taskbar, application-switcher

I'm using the Task-Switcher/Application-Switcher (Alt-Tab or Super-Tab) in Gnome. By pressing Alt-Tab I'm able to cycle through a list of open applications from left to right in the order in which they were last accessed. However it appears that Google Chrome violates this rule and remains in the leftmost slot even after I select another application. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?